# Matlab-While loops

Tags: matlab

Given an array I have to print numbers in the array which must be positive and divisible by 2, if the condition does not hold print "didn't find" only once.

I have run my code but get "didnt find" message for the entire length of the array. How do I code it so it only says its once?

Here's my code:

```
numbers = [9 3 7 3];
i = 1;    
while i <= length(numbers)
    if numbers(i)>0 && mod(numbers(i),2) == 0
        disp(numbers(i))
    else
        disp('didint find')
        i = i + 1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = [9 3 7 3];
found = false; %This is a boolean flag used to see if we have found a number fitting the rules. If we find no number, found will be still false at the end of the loop

for i = 1:length(numbers) %A for loop is far more suited to this problem than your original while

    if numbers(i)>0 && mod(numbers(i),2) == 0

       disp(numbers(i))
       found = true;

    end
end
if ~found
    disp('Didn''t find');
end
```

But in Matlab you could actually do this with no loop, in fact it is preferable not to use a loop. Try the following code:

```
ind = numbers > 0 & mod(numbers,2) == 0;
if ~any(ind)
    disp('Didn''t find');
else    
    disp(numbers(ind)');
end
```

Comment: How can i do it with a for loob?

Comment: @auriga123 See my edit, but the second version is better and you should try and understand that.